# Graphing the RGB Spectrum in VBA

Tags: vba, colors

Im working on a little project where I would like to be able to "graph" the RGB Spectrum. I want to create a visual representation of the full "spectrum." I have done this by using 3 sinusoidal functions for each color (R, G, and B) however, the graphic my program creates does not represent the full spectrum (I'm not looking for the full 16.8 million colors, but my graphic is lacking orange/yellow and a few other hues). Below is what I have so far.

```
Dim mul As Double, N As Double, i As Double
mul = 12
N = 3.14 * mul
For i = 1 To 10 Step 3.14 / 100
    Dim r As Double, b As Double, g As Double
    r = Sin(i)
    g = Sin(-1 * i)
    b = Cos(i)
    If r <= 0 Then r = 0
    If g <= 0 Then g = 0
    If b <= 0 Then b = 0
    Debug.Print Sin(i) * 250 & 1
    Cells(10, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(r * 255, g * 255, b * 255)
    Cells(11, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(r * 255, 0, 0)
    Cells(12, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, g * 255, 0)
    Cells(13, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, b * 255)


Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines like `If r <= 0 Then r = 0` make fully half of the values map to zero

A variation, thinking of the `r`, `g`, `b` values as being sinusoidal waves with a mean of `127.5` and an amplitude of `127.5` (so they go from 0 to 255) is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mul As Double, N As Double, i As Double
    Dim r As Long, b As Long, g As Long

    For i = 1 To 10 Step Application.Pi / 100
        r = Round(127.5 + 127.5 * Sin(i))
        g = Round(127.5 + 127.5 * Sin(-1 * i))
        b = Round(127.5 + 127.5 * Cos(i))
        Cells(10, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        Cells(11, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(r, 0, 0)
        Cells(12, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, g, 0)
        Cells(13, i * 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, b)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The following graphic shows the spectrum produced by your code (the top one) and the modified code. The modified code does seem to cover more of the spectrum:

[image]